# Qué responden a la siguiente pregunta: “¿Por qué debería unirme a SOes cuando ya existe un sitio en inglés?"

Tags: discusión, promoción-del-sitio

Para muchos de nosotros que estamos invitando a compañeros de trabajo, esta frase se escucha varias veces.  ¿Como responden ustedes a este razonamiento?

Comment: Podrías ponerla en destaque, no?

Answer (score 21):

Le diría algo como:

puedes unirte si:

- Te sientes más cómodo o por alguna razón prefieres preguntar y/o responder en español y no en inglés, por ejemplo, porque es tu lengua materna, porque tienes todavía alguna dificultad con el inglés o porque estás aprendiendo el idioma y te sirve para practicarlo.
- Lees y escribes perfectamente en inglés, te sientes cómodo en SO en inglés, pero quieres ayudar a otros programadores de habla hispana que aún no son tan hábiles en la lengua de Shakespeare. Esta ayuda puede venir:

  - Escribiendo respuestas originales a las preguntas planteadas por otros
  - Buscando respuestas en el SO en inglés para preguntas planteadas por otros, y escribir una respuesta que sea una traducción directa de la mejor respuesta en inglés, o **mejor aún**, que sea una respuesta original en español que contiene información tomada de varias respuestas en inglés, logrando un mejor contenido.
  - Traduciendo tus preguntas favoritas del sitio en inglés al español, y traduciendo la mejor respuesta o, al igual que en el punto anterior, mejorándola con información de varias respuestas.

Por ahora no se me ocurre otras razones, que debe haber varias, pero al final, si no casas en ninguna de esas, quizás no debas unirte.

Comment: excelentes razones!

Comment: El tema de las traducciones a pesar poder de ser válido es controversial, lo mejor es ahondar más en las otras razones

Comment: @Carlos, en base a las respuestas a la [discusión sobre traducciones](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/14/21), diría que no es tan controversial. Es cierto que he visto votos de castigo para quienes traducen, pero [ya he expresado mi opinión al respecto](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/325/21) en el mismo hilo.

Comment: Sobre la discución sobre traducciones, además del referido en le comentario del OP está este [otro](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/46/son-aceptables-las-traducciones-de-preguntas-de-stackoverflow-en-ingl%C3%A9s/) el cual tiene respuesta de @JuanM.

Answer (score 8):

Opino mas o menos igual que @jachguate pero para no repetir lo mismo añadiria lo siguiente:

Porque puedes aportar a las personas de habla hispana el conocimiento que puedas tener ya sea mucho o poco, y a los chavales que son muy jovenes (y no tan jovenes) les brindas la oportunidad de que puedan tener acceso a este tipo de material que los que hablan ingles tienen acceso a el desde hace años, con lo que un chaval de 10 o 15 años esta en desventaja con respecto a otro que hable ingles, con lo que el puede consultar comodamente la informacion de SO original, cosa que de no saber ingle no puede hacerlo,(por no hablar de preguntar en SO), ademas de no mencionar la cantidad de libros y documentacion en el idioma ingles, basicamente seria para que todos cuenten con la misma o por lo menos, parecidas herraminetas independientemente del idioma, para resolver dudas y ampliar conocimientos, pues no todo el contenido de SO original es escrito por hablantes nativos y espero que algun dia el contenido en este lugar tampoco sea escrito integramente por hispanohablantes.

(*cuando mucha veces se escucha*, no es que todo esta en ingles)y es casi 
verdad, pero por que un hispanohablantes no puede ser "y seguro que los hay"  ser como minimo tan bueno en una tecnologia como cualquier otro usuario (ingles nativo) que participe de SO (que una gran respuesta/as este/en escrita/as en ingles no quiere decir que sean ingleses), y sobre esto y como parte de la pregunta dice *"porque debería unirme..."* a lo que aplico:

*Porque no deberías* unirte y aportar tu grano de arena a la comunidad hispana y no solo a la inglesa, cuentes con muchos o con pocos conocimietos y si tienes muchos conocimientos y experiencia por que no compartirla de igual modo, y mas ahora que se cuenta con un sitio para ello.

> jaja esto era un comentario pero se me fue un poco y eso que no puse
>   lo que deje en el chat

Answer (score 6):

Mis razones (algunas de ellas están asociadas entre sí):

- No sabes o no conoces mucho el inglés y pasas más tiempo traduciendo y corrigiendo los errores del traductor que resolviendo el problema que tienes. Mejor usar tu idioma de habla materna o un idioma con el que te sientas más cómodo.
- Ya sabes inglés pero también decides/te gusta/prefieres ayudar a más personas brindando contenido en español.
- Estoy introduciéndome en el mundo de programación y provengo de un país/comunidad hispano hablante. No he tenido una buena enseñanza de inglés de niño/adolescente así que comenzar a buscar información en inglés me cuesta mucho. Al tener un sitio en español me siento más tranquilo y confiado de que podré brindar mis ideas y recibir apoyo de la comunidad.
- Oportunidad para contactar con más personas hispano hablantes que están sumergidas en este mundo. Este es más enfocado al chat que a la dinámica de preguntas/respuestas.
- Ya sé inglés (no necesariamente de manera nativa) pero quiero aprender/practicar español. He conocido un usuario con este perfil (su idioma materno es el francés), y me pareció interesante cómo utiliza el sitio de manera que puede reforzar el español y sus conocimientos de computación e informática.
- Porque [el español se habla más que el inglés](http://www.infoplease.com/ipa/A0775272.html) (información en inglés, al parecer confiable). Que existan más artículos en inglés que español sobre este tema no significa que el español deba quedarse atrás. Tampoco es que vamos a revolucionar el mundo, pero juntando el polvo se construye la montaña :D

Nota: Yo poseo cuenta en ambos sitios español e inglés

Answer (score 6):

## Razones estructurales

### SOes no es un clon de SO

- SOes no es una copia de SO. Si bien también trata los mismos temas que SO, incluye otros temas.

## Vivencia

### SOes está en fase de beta pública.

- Aprovecha, es una etapa que no se va a repetir y seguramente tomará mucho tiempo para el lanzamiento de otro sitio en español en la red de Stack Exchange.

## Social

### El lenguaje

El lenguaje y contexto de los participantes incide en la fluidez y tono de la comunicación. Aunque la idea central se pueda transmitir en inglés, el hacerl en español "sabe mejor".

### Networking

Por más profesional y técnico que sean los sitios principales, son un excelente medio para socializar, principalmente con expertos, algunos serán consolidados, otros en desarrollo.

Comment: +1 por networking, nadie havia dicho eso acá aún, estaban dejando escapar.

Comment: @Math eso lo había comentado en mi respuesta: *Oportunidad para contactar con más personas hispano hablantes que están sumergidas en este mundo* que está escrita 2 días antes que esta :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: He aquí un ejemplo de que la forma y la "terminología"   modifican el efecto :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza jajaja, probablemente se paso que he dicho el Rubén :)

Answer (score 5):

- Por capacidad de comunicación: Sin importar cuanto sepas de programación, si no sabes lo suficiente de inglés, no puedes participar *de la misma manera*. Tus aportes serán menos detallados, menos claros, menos útiles.
- Por la curva de aprendizaje: Siendo un requisito aprender ingles para aprender a programar, probablemente experimentes una curva de aprendizaje mucho mas lenta dada la dependencia. Participar aquí tiene el potencial de equiparar tus oportunidades frente a las de personas que saben inglés desde la cuna. Tiene el potencial de ahorrarte tiempo.
- Por inclusión social, solidaridad: Al participar en SOes, de algún modo estas *incluyendo al otro* (el que no sabe inglés) al universo del desarrollo de software y la programación. Quien sabe, quizá el próximo Alan Turing esta ahora en algún jardín de infantes en America Latina o en España.

Answer (score 4):

Con sinceridad comento que estaba en contra de un sitio en idioma español, en el que probablemente existirán preguntas repetidas, además la mayoría de los profesionales en informática deben al menos dominar ingles.

Pero recientemente encontré personas que están estudiando las cuales tienen como idioma nativo el Español, Griego, Rumano, etc. e inician cursos de ingles, incluso algunos no tienen un nivel básico, siempre les comentaba, entra a [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) y ahí encontraras una posible solución; al final era difícil para ellos obtener la información por la barrera del lenguaje, lo cual ahora para las personas de habla hispana será un lugar excelente para encontrar preguntas y respuestas acerca de su lenguaje de desarrollo favorito.

**¿Por qué debería unirme a SOes cuando ya existe un sitio en inglés?"**

**Tener un sitio en español provoca principalmente que esos usuarios que tenían limitantes en el sitio en inglés ahora se sientan mucho más cómodos tanto para preguntar como para participar ayudando a otros.**

Ahora gracias a la insistencia de @jachguate y otros, tenemos este sitio el cual seguramente será de gran ayuda para muchos futuros profesionales y profesionales en  TI.

> Prietenul la nevoie se cunoaste!

Comment: Cierto, a mi tampoco me parecía muy útil, pues incluso desincentivaría potencialmente el aprendizaje del inglés. Yo di un gran empujón a mi inglés técnico cuando tuve que empezar a trabajar en el mundillo, y la verdad que lo agradezco. Pero que éste portal sirva como antesala para empezar a mejorar y como índice de otras tantas preguntas y respuestas ya tratadas en stackoverlow (inglés) que simpre irá por delante, pues está bien. Así que, adelante con ello, y que esto facilite que mucha mas gente programe y comparta conocimeinto

Answer (score 3):

Porque pertenecemos a una cultura hispanohablante con un lenguaje riquísimo y el lenguaje como creación cultural establece los principios constitutivos de la identidad del individuo y de los grupos sociales, mediante las formas particulares en que se desarrollan los idiolectos, los dialectos y las lenguas, principalmente.

Por este motivo es un orgullo hablar y discutir sobre lo que más nos apasiona (en mi caso el desarrollo de código) en nuestra lengua materna, sin perjuicio a que podamos hablar, escribir y entender otros idiomas para comunicarnos con la diversidad de culturas existentes.

Answer (score 1):

Por democracia. Todos tienen derecho al acceso al conocimiento sin tener que sufrir las barreras idiomáticas. El que cierto conocimiento sólo esté en un idioma podría considerarse elitista, especialmente si este idioma es el usado por las clases sociales dominantes (un caso concreto: Inglés vs. Español).