# Un mes de beta publico - ¿ahora qué?

Tags: discusión

Me gustaría tomar un poco de tiempo para agradecerles por sus excelentes contribuciones al sitio.  Hemos disfrutado nuestro tiempo en beta publico por casi un mes y en ese tiempo he visto la cantidad de preguntas y respuestas crecer al igual que la membresía. Las más recientes estadísticas nos informan que estamos contribuyendo unas 11 preguntas a diario y llevamos un total de cerca de 600 preguntas.

Estos son buenos números y tengo la esperanza de que sigamos creciendo cada día más. De nuevo, ¡muchas gracias por su dedicación y ayuda a SOes!

Me agrada también que todos se han comportado con profesionalismo los unos con los otros.  No he visto situaciones en las que se ha demostrado la falta de respeto hacia alguien y eso mantiene con optimismo.  ¡Gracias por ser amistosos!

Mientras seguimos el paso adelante, veo dos cosas que quiero mencionar y espero que tengan opiniones y comentarios al terminar de leer esta publicación.

**Preguntas de baja calidad**

Cuando un usuario nuevo llega al sitio, preguntarán todo tipo de cosas y cometerán todo tipo de errores.  Muchas de sus preguntas serán obviamente generales o fuera de tema y necesitarán ser editadas antes de ser de uso al público.  Esto es normal y todos los sitios pasan por esto.  Lo mejor que se puede hacer en esas ocasiones es ser pacientes e intentar educar un poco a los novatos.

Les pido que sigamos dejando comentarios constructivos en esas preguntas de baja calidad.  Tratemos de no votar en contra tan rápidamente y de esperar un tiempo para dar oportunidad a que el autor original pueda mejorar su pregunta o respuesta. Continuemos siendo amables cuando publiquemos comentarios o ediciones.

Esto es lo que quiero evitar: **[Can I be successful using Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272850/can-i-be-successful-using-stack-exchange)**

Una advertencia, si ven spam en el sitio, repórtenlo.  Existirán excepciones a lo dicho, por favor usen discreción y su mejor juicio al responder.

**Publicidad del sitio**

Una de las mejores maneras de crecer nuestro sitio es recomendarlo a todos los que podamos.  Mientras más gente vea lo que hacemos, más se interesarán en añadirse a nuestra comunidad.  Si no nos has compartido por medio de las redes sociales, te animo a que lo hagas pronto.  Nosotros, como comunidad de habla hispana, tenemos la oportunidad de alcanzar a grandes grupos de desarrolladores en todo el mundo - gente a la que el sitio en inglés nunca alcanzará.  ¡Esa es la razón de nuestra existencia!

Sé que varios de ustedes han compartido nuestro sitio con sus compañeros de trabajo y una de las respuestas típicas ha sido, “[**¿Por qué debería unirme a SOes cuando ya existe un sitio en inglés?**](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360/qu%C3%A9-responden-a-la-siguiente-pregunta-por-qu%C3%A9-deber%C3%ADa-unirme-a-soes-cuando-ya)” Aquí les dejo una publicación para que lean sobre cómo podemos responder a esa pregunta.

¿Y tú, ya compartiste nuestro sito con tus conocidos?

No se les olvide seguirnos en Twitter: https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow

Comment: La variable Avid users también crece a diario!

Comment: @rnrneverdies ¡muy cierto!

Comment: Creo que deberíamos destacar que el crecimiento continuó incluso durante el maratón Guadalupe-Reyes(12 de diciembre - 6 de enero,  y sus variantes por país).

Comment: Ahora, a seguir adelante!!! Si continuamos con el ritmo que traemos, y se sigue creando contenido de buena calidad, el crecimiento del sitio está asegurado. Desconozco los números por los que comenzó Stack Overflow en Inglés, pero no dudo que esta comunidad será tan grande como pueda ser, y el crecimiento exponencial y masivo llegará a su debido momento.

Comment: Juan, creo que no hay necesidad de agradecer, todos amamos el sitio y es un apoyo desinteresado. Particularmente me gusta mucho como se está desarrollando SOes, sigamos siendo amistosos, evitemos discusiones, tengamos paciencia, seamos estrictos cuando tenemos que serlo y estoy seguro que las cosas irán mucho mejor. Muy pocas veces doy votos negativos pero estoy de acuerdo contigo en que tenemos que esperar un poco antes de bombardear con -1s a los nuevos integrantes.

Comment: A mi me echaron del stack original, creo que por una sóla respuesta que hice, que luego borré, y ahora no me dan chance, aún no me quitan el veto y no sé que hacer.

Comment: @SalahAdDin pero si veo que tienes cuenta activa: http://stackoverflow.com/users/3826549/salahaddin

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Claro, pero no puedo responder absolutamente nada por que tengo prohibido hacerlo, y lo peor, es que no tengo una sola respuesta. Creo que sólo puedo comentar.

Comment: Puedes abrir un tema en meta? O si no contactate directamente

Comment: de suerte encontre que esta español.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz, puedo abrir un tema en meta para solicitar que se me desbloquee en stack en inglés? realmente quiero aportar en stack en inglés, pero no puedo hacer nada, y eso me frustra, ya que me bloquearon recién llegaba a la comunidad.

Comment: @SalahAdDin Como te comenté, intenta abrir un tema en meta de allá o contactate directamente a través de su formulario de contacto