# ¿Agregamos el twitter de SOes en la información del sitio?

Tags: característica-nueva, estado-completado, promoción-del-sitio

En primer lugar es una pregunta a [Juan M](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m): ¿Te parece bien oficializar aún más la cuenta de twitter de SOes (https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow) dentro del listado de sitios?

---

Asumiendo el sí, que creo que es obvio porque *ya es oficial*, ¿no estaría bueno publicarlo en la [lista de sitios de Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday)?

[image: Lista de sitios de SE, donde el resto de los SO internacionales tiene el enlace a su cuenta de twitter y SOes no]

Creo que sólo está en Meta en [una publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/374/127) y, por más que no esperemos que incremente significativamente la participación, me parece que cualquier esfuerzo por publicitar el sitio, por más mínimo que sea, es bueno.

¿No les parece que vale la pena agregarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**¡Ya se agregó [la cuenta de twitter de SOes](https://twitter.com/esStackOverflow) al listado!**

[image: el sitio aparece con el enlace a la cuenta de Twitter]

---

> No sé cuándo (y me parece que no está relacionado a la graduación) pero recién, que leí una pregunta indirectamente relacionada, me acordé, lo busqué y ahí estaba.
>
> - ¡Gracias por considerarlo!