# ¿Cómo puedo motivar a ser parte de esta comunidad a alguien que nunca ha usado Stack Exchange?

Tags: discusión, promoción-del-sitio

Tengo algunos amigos y compañeros que nunca han usado Stack Exchange y me gustaría animarlos a que sean parte de esta comunidad. Sin embargo, les he comentado mi experiencia y al parecer no se sienten tan convencidos.

Algunos lo ven como un simple foro, o quizás son de los que el orgullo no les permite hacer una pregunta a desconocidos.

¿Que recomendaciones me darían para convencerlos de que prueben Stack Overflow en español?

*Relacionada: [Qué responden a la siguiente pregunta: “¿Por qué debería unirme a SOes cuando ya existe un sitio en inglés?"](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360/qu%C3%A9-responden-a-la-siguiente-pregunta-por-qu%C3%A9-deber%C3%ADa-unirme-a-soes-cuando-y)*

Comment: Esa pregunta esta enfocada a las personas que ya utilizan StackOverflow en inglés y no tienen motivos para usar el sitio en español. Mi pregunta esta enfocada a personas totalmente nuevas, que no hayan usado el sitio ni siquiera en inglés. Edite mi pregunta para intentar aclarar mejor mi punto.

Comment: Cierto, es casi duplicada pero no. De todas formas he añadido un enlace a la otra pregunta porque están muy relacionadas.

Comment: @JavierCárdenas haces una buena pregunta porque tengo el presentimiento que no serás el único en vivir esta experiencia

Answer (score 10):

Cuando te pregunten algo sobre programación, diles que estás muy ocupado pero con mucho gusto aprovecharás una pausa del ajetreo del día para responderla en SOes.

Comment: ¡genial la respuesta!

Answer (score 6):

Predica con el ejemplo.

¿Quires saber como se enlazan las variables lulillas a los objetos sicomórficos? Voy a buscarlo en SOes. Mira, este pone que se puede hacer compilando con rododendros. Pero este otro pone que si compilas con frindulios es más seguro; esto no lo sabía, ¡que bueno, voy a darle un positivo!

O si no hay nada sobre ese tema...
No hay nada, voy a poner una pregunta. Yo creo que compilando con rododendros ya va bien pero echa un vistazo de vez en cuando a ver si alguien responde algo mejor.
Al cabo de un tiempo le comentas : ¿Oye, has visto la pregunta que pusimos en SOes sobre el enlace de las variables lulillas a los objetos sicomórficos? Han puesto que compilando con frindulios es más seguro, igual te interesa, échale un vistazo.